# quickly jump to an object in Object Explorer in SSMS

Tags: ssms

When expanding a tree with a large number of objects such as the Tables tree in SSMS Object Explorer, is there a method of quickly navigating to the table I am looking for, if I know the exact name or the first few letters of the name? I know that by typing the table name, the explorer will navigate to the respective table, but with table names like dbo.Table1, I want to avoid typing the 'dbo' portion of the name and just start typing Table1. I am not looking to use Filtering as I find this is cumbersome when navigating dozens of times throughout the day. I am using SMSS V11.0.3128.0.

Comment: FWIW, if you use filtering you do not need to include the schema (dbo or other) in the filter. Of course, I understand you do not want to use filtering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the Object Explorer Details window.

It's the second option under the View menu or F7 to open it.  Once there you can just select the category in Object Explorer you want to look at (tables for example) and then in the OE Details window you can just type the name of the table.  As an added bonus you can sort by name, schema, create date and a number of other really useful columns.

[image]

Comment: This article has more information about using Object Explorer Details to navigate directory to the node. I'd just like to do a case insensitive search, so  searching on %Table1% would find tables  Table1 or TABLE1. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1935/using-object-explorer-details-and-object-search-feature-of-ssms-2008/

Answer (score 4):

[SSMSBoost](http://www.ssmsboost.com) add-in will do the job: allows to navigate from focused object in Script Editor to ObjectExplorer, or allows to script it directly. Also has "Objects Search". (I am the developer of the add-in)

[image: SSMSBoost add-in]

Answer (score 1):

There are some third party add-ins you can get to do these searches in addition to locating references in other objects.  RedGate has a free SQLSearch that works pretty well and DevArt also has a SQL Search, though I've not used this one.

https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/
https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/search/

Comment: ApexSQL Complete has a Goto object feature. I've bound it to a keyboard shortcut and it's about the best I've found so far.